# Dynamic ODATA service

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

Is there a ODATA provider that can be pointed at any database and provide CRUD operations against all tables in the database?

Microsoft's WCF Data Service provider uses EF data context so the schema of the database needs to be know at design time.

Comment: Do you have classes? do you want it to just infer the relationships by foreign keys? what database are you working against (this is going to have more impact on the answer than the fact you want a .NET solution).

Comment: yes, I need to infer all metadata from the database (SQL Server) itself, no classes for each table.

Comment: It can be done, it's a little bit more involved that you might like and it's hard to get right. Basically you build the EdmModel manually, so you will need to execute metadata queries against the server to iterate all the tables and then all the properties of those tables. It is far easier to use Entity Framework to build the model for you if you can

Comment: yep, involved it was... got it working finally :)